# Facebook API Post Search Deprecated?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to perform a search via the Facebook API and getting the following error from Facebook - `(#11) Post search has been deprecated`

URL I am using to query graph: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=search_query&type=post&access_token={access_token}`

Any ideas why this is happening as I can't seem to find anything about the post search being deprecated?

Comment: Be aware about this : "APIs are supported for at least two years after they're introduced, except for v1.0, which will only be available for one year after the release of v2.0."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Graph API v1.0 has been fully deprecated and is no longer available as a workaround. Original answer below for reference.

---

Yes, version 2.0 of the GraphAPI does not let you search for posts anymore. See the [updated documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search).

You can continue to search for posts by changing your API call to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=search_query&type=post&access_token={access_token}
```

I.e. add `v1.0/` after `https://graph.facebook.com/`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer - seems to me like Facebook are really missing a trick there!

Comment: Why exactly it was deprecated ? Is there a reason for this ?

Comment: @gaponov I haven't been able to find a reason, or much description as to why they have done this but its annoying they have!

Comment: Any idea if there will be a new method? And will `/v1.0/` ever go away?

Comment: There is no alternative at this time, and v1.0 with stop working after April 30th 2015.

Comment: Today i will receive "(#11) Post search has been deprecated" that response from Facebook API. Someone receive too?

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned [Niraj Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920568/niraj-shah), searching by the type "post" is already 'Legacy' API method and could be used with path '/v1.0/search?type=post', BUT there is one more trouble - your application can't use v1.0 API, if it was created after 30th April 2014. So be careful. According this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23523197/2742161).

Comment: ... and all apps have been upgraded to v2.x after April 30, 2015.

Answer (score 4):

According to Facebook, "All Facebook-enabled apps will be automatically upgraded to API v2.0 on April 30, 2015. If you have mobile apps, you'll need to update your app well before that date - leaving additional weeks for people to download your update from the store", and "Public post search is no longer available".

Check this for details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading