# How to gather public posts from Facebook for text analytics and real time streaming?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, data-mining

I tried using the Facebook Graph API for searching Facebook public posts. Since it is depreciated for v2.6, I tried the following command as given as an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491308/facebook-api-post-search-deprecated):
`https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=my_search_query&type=post&access_token=my_access_token`,
but gives the following error:
`"error": {
      "message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 11,
      "fbtrace_id": "AwAxoS4unJR"
   }
}`
 So it seems that I cannot do Post search any longer on Facebook Graph API. Moreover, I tried using the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/), but I get the following message on their API page:
`Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time.`
Thus, in order to get the data of public posts, I can think of only these two options:

1. Collaborate with [these companies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mediasolutions/partners) to get the post data
2. Scrape the Facebook website

Since I do not have enough budget to collaborate with some company, and I want to keep the scraping option at the end, is there any other option of getting public posts of Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scraping is not allowed on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

The only option is to collaborate with media partners.